# Disable BrowserSync in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, node.js, browser-sync

I use Node as a server. and I find out BrowserSync uses 100% of CPU. And I want to disable it. I searched a lot but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I figured out the sublime is the problem. Every time that a change made, sublime use a lot of resources to convert Typescript to JavaScript. So I used "Visual Studio Code" instead. This solved my problem and now I don't need to disable BrowserSync.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... if anybody can find a proper answer here.

Answer (score -1):

You need to rip out all browserSync-related code in gulp configuration files (usually in gulp/server.js), or whatever task manager you use:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['watch'], function () {
  // find and remove this or similar:
  browserSyncInit([path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve'), conf.paths.src]);
});
```

Search your project folder for `browserSync.init` or just `browserSync` to find the respective file.

Comment: I couldn't find anything. can you give a absolute path?

Comment: @JohnSparrow absolute path differs from system to system. What app building framework are you using ("angular2-seed", etc)?

Comment: I'm using angular2-seed

Comment: File: \tools\utils\seed\server.ts; comment out lines "codeChangeTool.listen();" and "codeChangeTool.changed(fileName);".

Comment: @JohnSparrow or: \tools\utils\seed\code_change_tools.ts, comment out lines: "browserSync.init(getPluginConfig('browser-sync'));" and "browserSync.reload(files);".